# Count of likes for image

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am creating an image gallery (images stored in Images folder,path saved in db) in the gridview

Each imagename is saved in dbwith and uinque id and the columnname : storyid.

can anyone tell me how to bind the indiviudal images "like" count in the lblcount

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="SM1">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial"
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="IncreaseButton" Text="Like" CommandName="Increase"
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCount"></asp:Label>
                            <div style="display: none;">
                                <asp:Label Text="<%#Bind('StoryId')%>" ID="lblStoryid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FilePath" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height="100"
                HeaderText="Preview Image">
                <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text="Description" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text="<%#Bind('Description')%>" ID="lblImageid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

```
public partial class Gallery : System.Web.UI.Page
```

{

```
private void bindimage()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
    string strQuery = "select * from story";


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        sda.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "Increase")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        Label listPriceTextBox = (Label)row.FindControl("lblStoryid");
        int storyId = Convert.ToInt32(listPriceTextBox.Text);
        string UserEmailid = "aditya.arjula@gmail.com";
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        string strQuery = "INSERT INTO Likes(storyId,UserEmailid) VALUES(@storyId,@UserEmailid)";
        string LikeCount = "SELECT COUNT(StoryId) FROM Likes Where StoryId=1001;;";
        Label lblStoryid = (Label)row.FindControl("lblStoryid");
        lblStoryid.Text = LikeCount;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        SqlCommand cmdl = new SqlCommand(LikeCount);
        cmdl.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdl.Connection = con;


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@storyId", storyId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmailid", UserEmailid);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;

         try
         {
             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             cmdl.ExecuteNonQuery();

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Response.Write(ex.Message);
         }
         finally
         {
             con.Close();
             con.Dispose();
         }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(StoryId) FROM Likes Where StoryId=1001;` - so according to this query the number of rows represent the number of likes?

Comment: If you are using `<% %>` to assign a value to a `lable` or some display control, then it should be inside `''`. I saw you are using it in `""` (`Text="<%#Bind('StoryId')%>"`). change this to `Text='<%#Bind('StoryId')%>'` then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pull the number of likes out when you pull the story record down in your `bindimage` method e.g.

```
SELECT Story.StoryId, Max(Description) As Description, Count(Likes.StoryId) as LikeCount from Story
INNER JOIN Likes On Likes.StoryId = Story.StoryId
GROUP BY Story.StoryId
```

Then you can bind the count like

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("LikeCount")%>' runat="server" ID="lblCount"></asp:Label>
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f275e/21).

Comment: SELECT * from story, Count(Likes.StoryId) As LikeCount INNER JOIN Likes On Likes.StoryId = 1001;                                      Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'Count'. i am getting this error. both stroy and Likes are individual tables. i did not defined any relationship between the columns

Comment: @user2621743 did you see my edit? The relationship is irrelevant you are using a JOIN to pull the tables together.

Comment: Sorry frnd my mistake,the query is working.Can y please suggest where i should keep the code to show the likes. I mean it should fetch the likes for individaula pic when the grid is populating. also it should increase or decrese the count whn the user click on the like button

Comment: @user2621743 you only need to call this code one and that's when you are binding the data to the grid view. Generally this is done in a non-postback page load.